# Change Computed Property on Click

Tags: arrays, vue.js, v-for, computed-properties

Is it possible to add/change the computed property inside the "v-for" with a click event?
I would like to be able to display the list of food based on their category when I click on the proper button.

If I click on the "fruit" button it will be

```html
 <div v-for="food in fruitCategory" :key="food.name" class="card">
      <p>{{ food.name }}</p>
    </div>
```

and "candy" button it would be

```html
 <div v-for="food in candyCategory" :key="food.name" class="card">
      <p>{{ food.name }}</p>
    </div>
```

Is this a good approach?

### Actual code below

```html
<template>
  <div class="layout">
    <button>all</button>
    <button>fruit</button>
    <button>candy</button>
    <div v-for="food in foods" :key="food.name" class="card">
      <p>{{ food.name }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
export default {
  name: 'Food',
  data() {
    return {
      foods: [
        { name: 'banana', category: 'fruit' },
        { name: 'orange', category: 'fruit' },
        { name: 'strawberry', category: 'fruit' },
        { name: 'gum', category: 'candy' },
        { name: 'fuzzy peach', category: 'candy' },
      ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    fruitCategory: function() {
      return this.foods.filter(function(food) {
        return food.category === 'fruit'
      })
    }
  },
  candyCategory: function() {
    return this.foods.filter(function(food) {
      return food.category === 'candy'
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd be inclined to have just a single computed property with `return food.category === this.category`, where `this.category` would be a `data` property set by the button click. Would something like that fit your requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to store the category in `data` and then you can use the filter dynamically.

here as a working example with a `cat` array that checks if the category is included.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  name: 'Food',
  data() {
    return {
      cat: ['fruit','candy'],
      foods: [
        { name: 'banana', category: 'fruit' },
        { name: 'orange', category: 'fruit' },
        { name: 'strawberry', category: 'fruit' },
        { name: 'gum', category: 'candy' },
        { name: 'fuzzy peach', category: 'candy' },
      ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    filtered: function() {
      var cat = this.cat;
      return this.foods.filter(function(food) {
        return cat.indexOf(food.category) >= 0;
      })
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <div class="layout">
    <button @click="cat=['fruit', 'candy']">all</button>
    <button @click="cat=['fruit']">fruit</button>
    <button @click="cat=['candy']">candy</button>
    <div v-for="food in filtered" :key="food.name" class="card">
      <p>{{ food.name }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```